# Find Hyperlinks in Text using Python (twitter related)

Tags: python, regex

How can I parse text and find all instances of hyperlinks with a string? The hyperlink will not be in the html format of `<a href="http://test.com">test</a>` but just `http://test.com`

Secondly, I would like to then convert the original string and replace all instances of hyperlinks into clickable html hyperlinks.

I found an example in this thread:

[Easiest way to convert a URL to a hyperlink in a C# string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32637/easiest-way-to-convert-a-url-to-a-hyperlink-in-a-c-string)

but was unable to reproduce it in python :(

Comment: You should use http://example.com for example URLs.  See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Example.com

Comment: Thanks John! I did not know that those are official example domains.

Comment: See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9760588/how-do-you-extract-a-url-from-a-string-using-python/31952097#31952097

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Here's a Python port of [Easiest way to convert a URL to a hyperlink in a C# string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32637/easiest-way-to-convert-a-url-to-a-hyperlink-in-a-c-string/32648#32648):

```
import re

myString = "This is my tweet check it out http://tinyurl.com/blah"

r = re.compile(r"(http://[^ ]+)")
print r.sub(r'<a href="\1">\1</a>', myString)
```

Output:

```
This is my tweet check it out <a href="http://tinyurl.com/blah">http://tinyurl.com/blah</a>
```

Comment: It can be improved by adding support for https or ftp URLs... Also, I believe the scheme (http) is case-INsensitive.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1986059/gruber-s-url-regular-expression-in-python for hopefully a better regular expression.

Answer (score 10):

[Here](http://mail.python.org/pipermail/tutor/2002-September/017228.html) is a much more sophisticated regexp from 2002.

@yoniLavi minified this to:

```
re.compile(r'\b(?:https?|telnet|gopher|file|wais|ftp):[\w/#~:.?+=&%@!\-.:?\\-]+?(?=[.:?\-]*(?:[^\w/#~:.?+=&%@!\-.:?\-]|$))')
```

Comment: I found it very useful too, and minified it to:
`re.compile(r'\b(?:https?|telnet|gopher|file|wais|ftp):[\w/#~:.?+=&%@!\-.:?\\-]+?(?=[.:?\-]*(?:[^\w/#~:.?+=&%@!\-.:?\-]|$))')`

Comment: Great stuff, but what if the URL does not have the http:// prefix.   Usually we don't specify that part any more in emails and social media.

Answer (score 5):

Django also has a solution that doesn't just use regex. It is [django.utils.html.urlize()](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/utils/html.py#L236). I found this to be very helpful, especially if you happen to be using django.

You can also extract the [code](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/utils/html.py#L236) to use in your own project.

Answer (score 2):

Jinja2 (Flask uses this) has a filter `urlize` which does the same.

[Docs](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/templates/#urlize)

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at [urlextract](https://github.com/lipoja/URLExtract).

You can install it running: `pip install urlextract`

```py
from urlextract import URLExtract

extractor = URLExtract()
urls = extractor.find_urls("Text with URLs. Let's have URL janlipovsky.cz as an example.")
print(urls) # prints: ['janlipovsky.cz']
```

The main advantage is that `urlextract` will find URLs without specifying schema (http, ftp, etc.) It also has a lot of configuration options to tune in the extractor to fit your needs. Everything can be found in [documentation](https://urlextract.readthedocs.io/en/latest/urlextract.html).

Comment: I like this library. As of this moment, it was last updated Dec 2022.

Comment: I know - lack of free time last year - I do not have it as much as years before - I welcome any PR with improvements and bug fixes. I hope that I will find time for maintenance this year :)