# Python regex - multiple search

Tags: python, regex, mechanize

Here is what I'm trying to accomplish:

1. Using python mechanize I open a site
2. If content does not match my regex I open another site
3. I perform searching using another regex

And the extracted code:

```
m = re.search('<td>(?P<alt>\d+)', response.read())
...
m = re.search('<td>(?P<alt>\w+)', response.read())
print m.group('alt')
```

I'm getting:

`AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'`

If I uncomment **the second search** everything is fine. I don't understand this behaviour.

Such an error redirected me to [this stackoverflow issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1491277/python-regex-object-has-no-attribute) and to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/597476/how-to-concisely-cascade-through-multiple-regex-statements-in-python) - but to no avail - neither of these solved my problem.

I don't care about efficiency here so I don't use `compile`.

Comment: What is the unfiltered result of each response.read()? I'm betting the second read isn't returning what you expect.

Comment: Could you add some more details about what you are trying to do by calling re.search twice? The current example code makes no sense.

Comment: @kramthegram - thanks! You're right. It wasn't regex issue. @shang - because response.read() changes beetween these 2 lines - vide second point of my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming `response` is a file-like object, calling `read` a second time might return a empty string as you consumed the file before.

```
data = response.read()
m = re.search('<td>(?P<alt>\d\d*)', data)
m = re.search('<td>(?P<alt>\d\d*)', data)
print m.group('alt')
```

Why would you call `search` multiple times?

Comment: You're right - thanks! So it wasn't regex issue. My mistake. I would like call search multiple times, because data might change between these two lines (second point of my question).

Comment: @laszchamachla In that case, I don't see how this is any help. If I understand you correctly, you're getting page A, search on its data, in case of no matches, you do a new request and search on that data. There shouldn't be a problem if between two searches, you issue a new request and get a new response.

Comment: @Reiner - exactly, it is pretty strange to me too. But, as you adviced, asigning response.read() to variable before every search solves the problem.

Comment: Also I'd suggest to compile the regex once: `rx = re.compile('<td>(?P<alt>\d\d*)')` and then re-use it wherever needed: `m = rx.search(data)`.

Comment: @9000 - I wrote: "I don't care about efficiency here so I don't use compile." - it is not the point in this case, but thanks for your suggestion.

Comment: @laszchamachla: besides efficiency, there's maintainability: you only need to change the regexp once if you find a bug in it. but you can just use a string constant, of course :)

Comment: @9000 - Thanks, I know that :) It was only an example - in fact I use different regexes to aforementioned searches.