# Find Hyperlinks in Text using Python (Follow-up to another post)

Tags: python, regex

In regards to ([Extracting a URL in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/839994/extracting-a-url-in-python)) I have a follow-up question.  Note: I'm new to SO and Python, so feel free to correct me on etiquette.

I pulled the regex from the above post and this works fine for me:

```
myString = """ <iframe width="640" height="390" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/24WIANESD7k?rel=0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe> """
print re.search("(?P<url>https?://[^\s]+)", myString).group("url")
```

However what I really need to do is loop through a data set that I have previously retrieved from a database.  So I did the below, which gives me a strange error, also below.

```
# Note: "data" here is actually a list of strings, not a data set     
for pseudo_url in data:
        print re.search("(?P<url>https?://[^\s]+)", str(pseudo_url)).group("url")
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "find_and_email_bad_press_urls.py", line 136, in <module>
    main()
  File "find_and_email_bad_press_urls.py", line 14, in main
    scrubbed_urls = extract_urls_from_raw_data(raw_url_data)
  File "find_and_email_bad_press_urls.py", line 47, in extract_urls_from_raw_data
    print re.search("(?P<url>https?://[^\s]+)", str(pseudo_url)).group("url")
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'
```

When I Google this I find tons of irrelevant posts, so I was hoping SO could shed some light.  My hunch is that the regex is blowing up on some null data, special character, etc., but I don't know enough about Python to figure it out.  Casting to a string didn't help either.

Any ideas or workarounds to power through this would be much appreciated!

Comment: I suggest you try the BeautifulSoup module for scraping data from HTML pages. Your error says that the regex returned no matches, and therefore a `None` object, which has no `group` attribute.

Answer (score 2):

Your regex is not finding a url in every string in `data`. You should check to make sure you have a match before making the call to `group`:

```
for pseudo_url in data:
    m = re.search("(?P<url>https?://[^\s]+)", pseudo_url)
    if m:
        print m.group("url")
```

You don't need the call to `str()` either if pseudo_url is already a string.

And as @Blender suggested in his comment, if `data` is really lines read from an HTML file, you may want to consider using Beautiful Soup instead of regex for this.

Comment: Thanks Blender & alan - that worked like a charm.  As I'm new to Python, I have no idea what the group function does.  Obviously if you're trying to perform an operation on null data you're going to have issues!  Now I just need to learn a little about group to feel comfortable.  Thanks again!

Comment: @Adam: Learn to love the docs: http://docs.python.org/library/re.html#re.MatchObject.group
 - and for the record, regex is not the best way to go about this. BeautifulSoup or another parser is a better solution.

Comment: @Adam glad it helped. If this answered your question, you might consider accepting the answer.