# Regex to validate port number

Tags: regex, vb.net, .net-2.0

I'm using this regex `(6553[0-5]|655[0-2]\d|65[0-4]\d{2}|6[0-4]\d{3}|[1-5]\d{4}|[1-9]\d{0,3}` to validate port numbers. Somehow this is not working. What is wrong with this? Can anybody point me out.

Comment: What are you trying to do?  Maybe post some unit test code that is failing or something?

Comment: what port numbers do you want 2 validate..are they in specific range or do u want it 2 just validate

Comment: @Fake.It.Til.U.Make.It I just want to validate from 1 to 65535.

Comment: @SohamDasgupta no need to use regex here..just parse the number to int and then check if it is in required range!

Answer (score 57, accepted):

What exactly do you mean by *not working*?

You could try something like so: `^([1-9][0-9]{0,3}|[1-5][0-9]{4}|6[0-4][0-9]{3}|65[0-4][0-9]{2}|655[0-2][0-9]|6553[0-5])$` (obtained from [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20151029043426/http://utilitymill.com/utility/Regex_For_Range)).

This will make sure that any given string is numeric and between the range of `0` and `65535`.

Assuming your regular expression matches the same range, it is missing the start and end anchors (`^` and `$` respectively), so it would allow other strings besides the actual port.

*Update 2 Feb 2022:* Fixed the regex to reject values like `00` etc. The updated regex is sourced from [the comment below](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12968093/regex-to-validate-port-number#comment89586361_12968117). This regex can be better understood and visualized here: https://www.debuggex.com/r/jjEFZZQ34aPvCBMA

Comment: I'm using DexExpress textbox and using this regex as mask. But at runtime its generating an error saying incorrect syntax.

Comment: @SohamDasgupta: Maybe you need to put everything between quotation marks? Maybe looking at [the](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/CustomDocument1501) documentation will help.

Comment: Putting qoutes is something I learned 10yrs back when I started programming. Anyway thanks.

Comment: The first part (`[0-9]{1,4}`) is incorrectly allowing `0000`. It should be `[1-9]\\d{0,3}|0`

Comment: Hi, @elfan that accept 00 or 000 or 0000 

I find accidentally this entry and realized there is a little mistake in the pattern:

"After correction of your regexp :
Port = '([1-9][0-9]{0,3}|[1-5][0-9]{4}|6[0-4][0-9]{3}|65[0-4][0-9]{2}|655[0-3][0-9]|6553[0-5])'; // 1..65535"

This Pattern is allowed for the range between 1-65539, it should be:
Port = '([1-9][0-9]{0,3}|[1-5][0-9]{4}|6[0-4][0-9]{3}|65[0-4][0-9]{2}|655[0-2][0-9]|6553[0-5])'; // 1..65535

https://github.com/findhit/proxywrap/issues/13

Answer (score 14):

When, we search "how to validate port number" on Google we unfortunately land here

However (except if you have really no other choice...),

**Regex is clearly not the way to validate a port number !**

"One" (slightly better) way may be:

```
step 1: Convert your string into number, and return FALSE if it fails
step 2: return TRUE if your number is in [1-65535] range, and FALSE otherwise
```

**Various reasons, why Regex is not the right way ?**

- Code readability (would takes few minutes to understand)
- Code robustness (there are various ways to introduce a typo, a unitary test would be required)
- Code flexibility (what if port number can be extended to a 64-bits number !?)
- etc. ...

Comment: Good suggestion. For step 1,we can use `System.UInt16.Tryparse(string value, out int result)`. Although `UInt16` range includes zero as well which is not a valid port number.

Answer (score 4):

Here is the example I'm using to validate port settings for a firewall. The original answer will match 2 strings. I can only have 1 string match.

`(6553[0-5]|655[0-2][0-9]|65[0-4][0-9][0-9]|6[0-4][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]|[1-5](\d){4}|[1-9](\d){0,3})`

To get: `22,24:100,333,678,100:65535` my full validation (That will only return 1 match) is

```
(6553[0-5]|655[0-2][0-9]|65[0-4][0-9][0-9]|6[0-4][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]|[1-5](\d){4}|[0-9](\d){0,3})(:(6553[0-5]|655[0-2][0-9]|65[0-4][0-9][0-9]|6[0-4][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]|[1-5](\d){4}|[0-9](\d){0,3}))?(,(6553[0-5]|655[0-2][0-9]|65[0-4][0-9][0-9]|6[0-4][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]|[1-5](\d){4}|[0-9](\d){0,3}){1}(:(6553[0-5]|655[0-2][0-9]|65[0-4][0-9][0-9]|6[0-4][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]|[1-5](\d){4}|[0-9](\d){0,3}))?)*
```

Answer (score 3):

Number() is the function you want "123a" returns NAN

parseInt() truncates trailing letters "123a" returns 123

```
<input type="text" id="txtFld" onblur="if(Number(this.value)>0 && Number(this.value)<65536){alert('valid port number');}" />
```

- [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/at8ay/3/)

Comment: Too late :) , but this is obviously wrong. You can test it with "2e2" for example.

Answer (score 2):

A more strict approach is to have a regex matching all numbers up to 5 digits
with the following string:

```
*(^[1-9]{1}$|^[0-9]{2,4}$|^[0-9]{3,4}$|^[1-5]{1}[0-9]{1}[0-9]{1}[0-9]{1}[0-9]{1}$|^[1-6]{1}[0-4]{1}[0-9]{1}[0-9]{1}[0-9]{1}$|^[1-6]{1}[0-5]{1}[0-4]{1}[0-9]{1}[0-9]{1}$|^[1-6]{1}[0-5]{1}[0-5]{1}[0-3]{1}[0-5]{1}$)*
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is single port regex validation that excludes ports that start with 0

`^([1-9][0-9]{0,3}|[1-5][0-9]{4}|6[0-4][0-9]{3}|65[0-4][0-9]{2}|655[0-2][0-9]|6553[0-5])`

Here is validation for port range (ex. 1111-1111)

`^([1-9][0-9]{0,3}|[1-5][0-9]{4}|6[0-4][0-9]{3}|65[0-4][0-9]{2}|655[0-2][0-9]|6553[0-5])(-([1-9][0-9]{0,3}|[1-5][0-9]{4}|6[0-4][0-9]{3}|65[0-4][0-9]{2}|655[0-2][0-9]|6553[0-5]))?$`

link:

https://github.com/findhit/proxywrap/issues/13

Answer (score 2):

```
"^((6553[0-5])|(655[0-2][0-9])|(65[0-4][0-9]{2})|(6[0-4][0-9]{3})|([1-5][0-9]{4})|([0-5]{0,5})|([0-9]{1,4}))$"
```

It will allow everything between 0-65535 inclusive.

Answer (score 2):

Landed here as well, searching specifically for REGEX to validate port number.
I see the approved solution was not fixed yet to cover all scenarios ( eg: 007 port, and others ) and solutions from other sites not updated either ([eg](https://www.regextester.com/104146)).

Reached same minimal solution as `saber tabatabaee yazdi`, that should cover the `1-65535` range properly:

`^([1-9][0-9]{0,3}|[1-5][0-9]{4}|6[0-4][0-9]{3}|65[0-4][0-9]{2}|655[0-2][0-9]|6553[0-5])$`

Enjoy !

Answer (score 2):

```
^((6553[0-5])|(655[0-2][0-9])|(65[0-4][0-9]{2})|(6[0-4][0-9]{3})|([1-5][0-9]{4})|([0-5]{0,5})|([0][0-9]{1,4})|([0-9]{1,4}))$
```

I have tested above regrex with Junit run the for loop from 0-65535

Ex: 00001 - 65535 with leading Zeros
1 - 65535 without leading Zeros
Ex:====

1. `(6553[0-5])`      : 65530-65535
2. `(655[0-2][0-9])`  : 65500-65529
3. `(65[0-4][0-9]{2})`: 65000-65499
4. `(6[0-4][0-9]{3})` : 60000-64999
5. `([1-5][0-9]{4})`  : 10000-59999
6. `([0-5]{0,5})`     : 00000-55555 (for leading Zeros)
7. `([0][0-9]{1,4})`   : 00000-09999  (for leading Zeros)
8. `([0-9]{1,4})`     : 0000-9999   (for leading Zeros)

Answer (score 1):

The accpeted answer by npinti is not right. It will not allow to enter port number 1000, for example. For me, this one (not nice, I'm a beginner) works correctly:

`/^((((([1-9])|([1-9][0-9])|([1-9][0-9][0-9])|([1-9][0-9][0-9][0-9])|([1-6][0-5][0-5][0-3][0-5])))))$/`

Answer (score 1):

@npinti 's answer  allows leading zeros in the port number and also port 0 means pick any available port so I would exclude that so the regex becomes

```
^([1-9][0-9]{0,4}|[1-5][0-9]{4}|6[0-4][0-9]{3}|65[0-4][0-9]{2}|655[0-2][0-9]|6553[0-5])$
```

If you want to allow port 0 then

```
^(0|[1-9][0-9]{0,4}|[1-5][0-9]{4}|6[0-4][0-9]{3}|65[0-4][0-9]{2}|655[0-2][0-9]|6553[0-5])$
```

Comment: I really like the intent of this answer as I have the exact same problem right now. Notice that your main difference is that the first capture group allows `[1-9][0-9]{0,4}`, but this means numbers like 99999 can get in, which violates the question. I'll keep trying to see if I can find a correction for this.

Comment: I think you meant to use `[1-9][0-9]{0,3}` instead? This will cover 1-9999 inclusive, but disallow leading zeroes.

Answer (score 1):

The solution:

```
Dim Minlenght As Integer = 1
Dim Maxlenght As Integer = 65536

Regex.IsMatch(sInput,"(^\d{0},{1}$)", "{" + Minlenght, Maxlenght + "}")
```

Answer (score 1):

If variable is an integer between 1 and 65536 (inclusive) then...

```
if [[ "$port" =~ ^[0-9]+$ && $port -ge 1 && $port -le 65536 ]]; then
```