# Yara regex for detecting port numbers not working

Tags: regex, port, yara

So I have been trying to build a regex that would detect port numbers(0-65535).
I have tried the one given in the post below:

[Regex to validate port number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12968093/regex-to-validate-port-number)

this one :

```
^([0-9]{1,4}|[1-5][0-9]{4}|6[0-4][0-9]{3}|65[0-4][0-9]{2}|655[0-2][0-9]|6553[0-5])$
```

The above one seems to work fine when testing on https://regex101.com/.

But when I try to build a yara rule to detect this with the same pattern as stated above it doesn't work even though the above pattern has all the allowed characters as stated in the documentation:

https://yara.readthedocs.io/en/stable/writingrules.html#regular-expressions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace `^` and `$` by `\b`.

```
\b([0-9]{1,4}|[1-5][0-9]{4}|6[0-4][0-9]{3}|65[0-4][0-9]{2}|655[0-2][0-9]|6553[0-5])\b
```

`\b` is a word boundary; The boundary between word-characters (`[A-Za-z0-9_]`) and non-word characters (anything else). The pattern would match a number between 0 and 65535 without any surrounding digit or letter.

Answer (score 0):

Your regex has starting (^) and end point ($) check.
Because of this it will work only if your input is a port number.
This will not work if you want to match the port number part from a string.
To work this for a string remove ^ and $ from the regex start and end point.

Comment: When I put these characters at the start and beginning, It does not detect any port number I give it (for example 4444) . Do note that I am using this in yara rule. 
And when I remove the characters from start and beginning, it just sees every number i input as a port number.
my regex:/([0-9]{1,4}|[1-5][0-9]{4}|6[0-4][0-9]{3}|65[0-4][0-9]{2}|655[0-2][0-9]|6553[0-5])/

Comment: Replace `^` and `$` by `\b` then. `\b` is a word boundary; The boundary between word-characters (`[A-Za-z0-9_]`) and non-word characters (anything else). The pattern would match a number between 0 and 65535 without any surrounding digit or letter.

Comment: Is this what you are suggesting?
/\b([0-9]{1,4}|[1-5][0-9]{4}|6[0-4][0-9]{3}|65[0-4][0-9]{2}|655[0-2][0-9]|6553[0-5])\b/

Comment: @MarkusJarderot can you kindly post this as an answer so I can accept it.
Thanks again