# Find all HTML and non-HTML encoded URLs in string

Tags: python, html, regex, beautifulsoup, lxml

I would like to find all URLs in a string. I found various solutions on StackOverflow that vary depending on the content of the string.

For example, supposing my string contained HTML, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1080411/retrieve-links-from-web-page-using-python-and-beautifulsoup?lq=1) recommends using either `BeautifulSoup` or `lxml`.

On the other hand, if my string contained only a plain URL without HTML tags, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/839994/extracting-a-url-in-python) recommends using a regular expression.

I wasn't able to find a good solution given my string contains both HTML encoded URL as well as a plain URL. Here is some example code:

```
import lxml.html

example_data = """<a href="http://www.some-random-domain.com/abc123/def.html">Click Me!</a>
http://www.another-random-domain.com/xyz.html"""
dom = lxml.html.fromstring(example_data)
for link in dom.xpath('//a/@href'):
    print "Found Link: ", link
```

As expected, this results in:

```
Found Link:  http://www.some-random-domain.com/abc123/def.html
```

I also tried the `twitter-text-python` library that @Yannisp mentioned, but it doesn't seem to extract both URLS:

```
>>> from ttp.ttp import Parser
>>> p = Parser()
>>> r = p.parse(example_data)
>>> r.urls
['http://www.another-random-domain.com/xyz.html']
```

What is the best approach for extracting both kinds of URLs from a string containing a mix of HTML and non HTML encoded data? Is there a good module that already does this? Or am I forced to combine regex with `BeautifulSoup`/`lxml`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I upvoted because it triggered my curiosity. There seems to be a library called [twitter-text-python](https://github.com/edburnett/twitter-text-python), that parses Twitter posts to detect both urls and hrefs. Otherwise, I would go with the combination regex + lxml

Comment: That looks like a cool library. I took a peek at the source and it appears the author manually extracts the URL. I updated my question with the results of my testing this library.

Comment: Accepting your answer, as the `twitter-text-python` helped me fill the gap that `lxml` left. I ended up using both. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You could use RE to find all URLs:

```
import re
urls = re.findall("(https?://[\w\/\$\-\_\.\+\!\*\'\(\)]+)", example_data)
```

It's including alphanumerics, '/' and ["Characters allowed in a URL"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1856785/characters-allowed-in-a-url)

Answer (score 0):

Based on the answer by @YannisP, I was able to come up with this solution:

```
import lxml.html  
from ttp.ttp import Parser

def extract_urls(data):
    urls = set()
    # First extract HTML-encoded URLs
    dom = lxml.html.fromstring(data)
    for link in dom.xpath('//a/@href'):
        urls.add(link)
    # Next, extract URLs from plain text
    parser = Parser()
    results = parser.parse(data)
    for url in results.urls:
        urls.add(url)
    return list(urls)
```

This results in:

```
>>> example_data
'<a href="http://www.some-random-domain.com/abc123/def.html">Click Me!</a>\nhttp://www.another-random-domain.com/xyz.html'
>>> urls = extract_urls(example_data)
>>> print urls
['http://www.another-random-domain.com/xyz.html', 'http://www.some-random-domain.com/abc123/def.html']
```

I'm not sure how well this will work on other URLs, but it seems to work for what I need it to do.