# Using re to pull out url

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to use `re` to pull out a url from something I have scraped. I am using the below code to pull out the data below but it seems to come up empty. I am not very familiar with re. Could you give me how to pull out the url?

```
match = ["http://www.stats.gov.cn/tjsj/zxfb/201811/t20181105_1631364.html';", "http://www.stats.gov.cn'+urlstr+'"]

url = re.findall('http[s]?://(?:[a-zA-Z]|[0-9]|[$-_@.&+]|[!*\(\),]|(?:%[0-9a-fA-F][0-9a-fA-F]))+', match`

#print url just prints both. I only need the match = "http://www.stats.gov.cn/tjsj/zxfb/ANYTHINGHERE/ANYTHINGHERE.html"

print(url)

Expected Output = ["http://www.stats.gov.cn/tjsj/zxfb/201811/t20181105_1631364.html';"]
```

Comment: Do you wanna take url from javascript files or from the HTML page source file?

Comment: If you just want to take a href link on the HTML page source a simple script like that should do the trick:  `#!/usr/bin/python
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup
except ImportError:
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
html = """put html here"""
parsed_html = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
for link in parsed_html.find_all('a'):
    print(link.get('href'))`

Comment: If you want to get the url, this will do the trick. I assume here the URL always start with http. __http:[^']+__

Comment: That’s easy stuff but the problem is there’s a JavaScript that runs and spits out the url.

Comment: @lucas_7_94 if the OP has to manage shattered or mangled html source code should be better not to use regex

Comment: @shadowsheep I’m trying to pull the url from the JavaScript file

Comment: I am already using beautifulsoup to scrape the page data by using findAll. I wouldn’t treat this as a beautifulsoup parse problem but just treat it as extracting the url from a string.

Comment: ah, okay. In this case a regex approach should be better. But there could be any possibility to run this javascript inside a fake html page of yours? If you only want to extract url from string in python that's a duplicate question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/839994/extracting-a-url-in-python

Comment: @shadowsheep thanks for the feedback. Could you help with one other thing? I don’t see how to get the specific url out that I used in the original question. How can I get only the urls that have the correct link without getting a ton of the useless urls with findall?

Comment: Do you mean something like that? `for link in parsed_html.find_all('a'):
    if (re.compile('www.stats.gov').search(link.get('href'))):
        print(link.get('href'))` In comments... source code is really ugly [-:

Comment: It should be better that you provide an example input and the expected output that you want to obtain and some code that runs so that people can test based on your current running code.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/183197/discussion-between-kamikaze-goldfish-and-shadowsheep).

Comment: @shadowsheep I fingered it out. See below and give me your feedback.

Comment: Happy you figured it out. There are many regex that could be the job, but if you found one that fits your need we are all happy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay I found the solution. The .+ looks for any number of characters between http://www.stats.gov.cn/ & .html. Thanks for your help with this.

```
match = ["http://www.stats.gov.cn/tjsj/zxfb/201811/t20181105_1631364.html';", "http://www.stats.gov.cn'+urlstr+'"]

url = re.findall('http://www.stats.gov.cn/.+.html', str(match))

print(url)

Expected Output = ["http://www.stats.gov.cn/tjsj/zxfb/201811/t20181105_1631364.html"]
```