# How can I capture the URL from regex in Python?

Tags: python, regex

```
import re   
string = """position":1,"url":"https://www.flipkart.com/honor-8c-black-64-gb/p/itmfc8c4fsekrpdp?pid=MOBFC8C8FXXNHZ7C&lid=LSTMOBFC8C8FXXNHZ7CZYQGKP&marketplace=FLIPKART,"""
regex = "\w\w\w\w\w\w\w\w\W\W\d\W\W\w\w\w\W\W\W\w\w\w\w\w\W\/\/(...)\"\W"             
match = re.findall(regex, string)  
print(match)
```

I want to capture just the link from the above variable 
the output must be in this way -(https://www.flipkart.com/honor-8c-black-64-gb/p/itmfc8c4fsekrpdp?pid=MOBFC8C8FXXNHZ7C&lid=LSTMOBFC8C8FXXNHZ7CZYQGKP&marketplace=FLIPKART)
while i run the above code it just gives me empty parenthesis

I think so that something is wrong with my regex so anyone please help me

THANKING IN ADVANCE.

Comment: check out the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/839994/extracting-a-url-in-python)

Comment: That string looks like its part of a larger serialized data stream. Is it JSON? If so, the answer is to parse the JSON. Urls are difficult to express in a single regex.

Comment: Maybe regex `url":,".*?"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have some formatting issues. Here you go (assuming this format is consistent, otherwise follow the advice from the comments):

```py
import re

string ='"position":1,"url":"https://www.flipkart.com/honor-8c-black-64-gb/p/itmfc8c4fsekrpdp?pid=MOBFC8C8FXXNHZ7C&lid=LSTMOBFC8C8FXXNHZ7CZYQGKP&marketplace=FLIPKART"'
regex = r'\"url\":\"(.*)\"'
match = re.search(regex, string)

print(match.group(1))
```