# Gruber’s URL Regular Expression in Python

Tags: python, regex, gruber

How do I rewrite this [new way to recognise](http://alanstorm.com/url_regex_explained) addresses to work in Python?

`\b(([\w-]+://?|www[.])[^\s()<>]+(?:\([\w\d]+\)|([^[:punct:]\s]|/)))`

Comment: Which part doesn't work?

Comment: Why don't you put your code in the question, with examples of what fails

Comment: @vanity, the answer with Unicode character properties won't work.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1832893/python-regex-matching-unicode-properties

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The [original source](http://daringfireball.net/2009/11/liberal_regex_for_matching_urls) for that states "This pattern should work in most modern regex implementations" and specifically Perl.  Python's regex implementation is modern and [similar to Perl's](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html#module-re) but is missing the `[:punct:]` character class.  You can easily build that using this:

```
>>> import string, re
>>> pat = r'\b(([\w-]+://?|www[.])[^\s()<>]+(?:\([\w\d]+\)|([^%s\s]|/)))'
>>> pat = pat % re.sub(r'([-\\\]])', r'\\\1', string.punctuation)
```

The `re.sub()` call escapes certain characters inside the character set [as required](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html#regular-expression-syntax).

**Edit**: Using re.escape() works just as well, since it just sticks a backslash in front of *everything*.  That felt crude to me at first, but certainly works fine for this case.

```
>>> pat = pat % re.escape(string.punctuation)
```

Comment: This passes all of Gruber's tests, as does pat = pat % re.escape(string.punctuation)

Comment: @vanity, updated to mention that.  Note the obvious, that if your data source is Unicode a pure-ASCII solution like string.punctuation may give imperfect results.

Comment: It works with non-ASCII domains and paths. I don't have test data with non-English punctuation.

Answer (score 5):

I don't think python have this expression

```
[:punct:]
```

[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression#POSIX_character_classes) says `[:punct:]` is same to

```
[-!\"#$%&\'()*+,./:;<=>?@\\[\\\\]^_`{|}~]
```

Comment: Wikipedia is wrong.  It's missing the caret, according to http://www.regular-expressions.info/posixbrackets.html.

Comment: Yeah, Updated my post, Thanks. Somebody updated Wikipedia too. Great!

Answer (score 2):

Python doesn't have the [POSIX bracket expressions](http://www.regular-expressions.info/posixbrackets.html).

The `[:punct:]` bracket expression is equivalent in ASCII to

```
[!"#$%&'()*+,\-./:;<=>?@[\\\]^_`{|}~]
```

Comment: Make sure you use a "raw" string (prefix with `r`) when using that, as the backslash escapes won't be correct otherwise.

Comment: Also note that Python does not support those Unicode character properties: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1832893

Comment: Indeed, they compile fine but don't do what you expect

Comment: Python's regex engine is a very strange beast. Fixed the answer.