# Python equivalents to Perl's URI::Find

Tags: python, perl

In Python, are there any modules for extracting plain urls from a string like Perl's URI::Find does?

Thanks.

Comment: Do you mean something other than using RegEx?

Comment: guess you could solve it using regex: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/720113/find-hyperlinks-in-text-using-python-twitter-related

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a [regex](http://mail.python.org/pipermail/tutor/2002-February/012481.html)  which can help you find the urls in text. There is no famous package in python which does uri::find in plain text. The sphinx documentation project however, includes a builder called `linkcheck` which finds all the links and checks for validity. You can check it's source too, but the linked regex is somewhat simpler.

If you simply care about http and https, the answer [is here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/839994/extracting-a-url-in-python)