# Problem with Regex to detect a hyperlink in C#

Tags: c#, regex, visual-studio-2010, replace

I am working in replacing a text with a hyperlink in C#. The problem here is..

**Case 1:No problem**

Input: ASAss12345

Output:[ASAss12345](http://stack.com/=ASAss12345)

**Case 2:Problem here**

Input: [ASAss12345](http://stack.com/=ASAss12345)

Output:[ASAss12345](http://stack.com/=ASAss12345)'>ASAss12345

Preferred Output: [ASAss12345](http://stack.com/=ASAss12345)

How can I rectify this problem. Code her for your reference.

```
mailItem.HTMLBody = Regex.Replace(mailItem.HTMLBody, "(?<!http://stack.com/=)ASA[a-z][a-z][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9](?!</a>)", "<a href='http://stack.com/=$&'>$&</a>");
```

Comment: @think: FYI, there's no such thing as "C Sharp". The language is named "C#".

Comment: Take a look at this...http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32637/easiest-way-to-convert-a-url-to-a-hyperlink-in-a-c-string

Comment: ThinkKool: i had just checked ur code on my own and find it running perfectly...

Comment: Really! it is weird.. I tried this just now.. I does not work for me..

Comment: Can u just skip the hyper linked text ?? i dont understand in case 2 , you are entering Hyperlinked text and in return u need the same hypelinked text again ?? one way can be to skip the Hyperlinked text and should only work for the text which is not hyperlinked....

Comment: @ThinkKool: may be error is something related with mailitem.htmlbody

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a  look at this.

i think you are looking for [This](http://4rapiddev.com/csharp/auto-convert-text-to-url-link-and-mailto-email-address-with-asp-net-c/)

Comment: Converts string to hyperlink.thats what u have asked.

Comment: How do I define LiteralName and site. They do exist in the current context. Also, where does Literalname.Text identify the regex pattern?

Comment: if u enter ASAss12345 then u need http://stack.com/r=ASAss12345..i didnt get that fr the 1st time.. its not complete answer but u should get ur answer from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32637/easiest-way-to-convert-a-url-to-a-hyperlink-in-a-c-string    did u check that?

Comment: @ThinkKool: I had not checked before but i have just tested ur code on my own and found its running perfectly...I donno what mailItem.HTMLBody (something related with outlook ) is but if u try the same thing on Label.Text its work perfectly..