# How to convert unclickable plain text URLs to links in HTML source

Tags: javascript, c#, html-agility-pack

I want to detect URLs and make them link in HTML code. I've searched Stack Overflow but many answers are about detecting and converting links in text strings. When I do that html code will be invalid; ie. img sources will change, etc.

P.S: Close voters: Please read question carefully! It's not duplicate.

For example; the line 1 needs to be converted, and lines 2 & 3 do not.

```
<!-- Sample html source -->
<div>
   Line 1 : https://www.google.com/
   Line 2 : <a href="https://www.google.com/">https://www.google.com/</a>
   Line 3: <img src="http://a-domain.com/lovely-image.jpg">
</div>
```

I need to:

> 1. Find any URL in html body part
> 2. Check if it is clickable or not: 
>      If not wrapped by 'a', 'img', '!--', etc..
> 3. If not make it clickable: 
>      Wrap with 'a'

How can I do that? All C# and JS versions are OK to me.

**LATEST UPDATE** Changing project build target from 4.7.2 to 4.5 and back to 4.7.2 fixed the "bug".

**UPDATE:** This is my solution with help of @jira
The problem here is nodes won't change at all. I mean the recursive function does the job, replaces links, debugging says, however html document won't update at all. Any modification inside the function doesn't effect outside of the function, I don't know why, **InnerText changes - InnerHtml doesn't change**

```
var htmlVersion = "<html><head></head><body>\r\n"
   + "Some text\r\n"
   + "<div>http://google.com</div>\r\n"
   + " Then later more text: http://500px.com\r\n"
   + "<div>Sub <span>abc</span> Back text</div>\r\n"
   + "And the final text"
   + "</body></html>";

var doc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
doc.LoadHtml(htmlVersion);

// Linkify body
var modified = false;
var bodyNode = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//body"); 
var before = bodyNode.InnerHtml;
bodyNode = Linkify(bodyNode);
modified = modified || bodyNode.InnerHtml != before;
// modified is false !!!
```

The recursive Linkify function:

```
HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlNode Linkify(HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlNode node)
{
    if (node.Name == "a") // It's already a link
    {
        return node;
    }

    if (node.Name == "#text") // Do replacement here
    {

        // Create links
        // https://stackoverflow.com/a/4750468/627193
        node.InnerHtml = Regex.Replace(node.InnerHtml,
            @"((http|ftp|https):\/\/[\w\-_]+(\.[\w\-_]+)+([\w\-\.,@?^=%&amp;:/~\+#]*[\w\-\@?^=%&amp;/~\+#])?)",
            "<a target='_blank' href='$1'>$1</a>");

    }

    for (int i = 0; i < node.ChildNodes.Count; i++) // Go for child nodes
    {
        node.ChildNodes[i] = Linkify(node.ChildNodes[i]);
    }
    return node;
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Easiest way to convert a URL to a hyperlink in a C# string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32637/easiest-way-to-convert-a-url-to-a-hyperlink-in-a-c-sharp-string)

Comment: Can you show your attempt to solve this?

Comment: @ChristianGollhardt No! It replaces in plain text and disturbs html links.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After changing project build target from 4.7.2 to 4.5 and go back to 4.7.2 again fixed the "bug".

Here is the working code:

```
var htmlVersion = "<html><head></head><body>\r\n"
   + "Some text\r\n"
   + "<div>http://google.com</div>\r\n"
   + " Then later more text: http://500px.com\r\n"
   + "<div>Sub <span>abc</span> Back text</div>\r\n"
   + "And the final text"
   + "</body></html>";

var doc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
doc.LoadHtml(htmlVersion);

// Linkify body
var modified = false;
var bodyNode = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//body"); 
var before = bodyNode.InnerHtml;
bodyNode = Linkify(bodyNode);
modified = modified || bodyNode.InnerHtml != before;
```

The recursive Linkify function:

```
HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlNode Linkify(HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlNode node)
{
    if (node == null || node.Name == "a") // It's already a link
    {
        return node;
    }

    if (node.Name == "#text") // Do replacement here
    {

        // Create links
        // https://stackoverflow.com/a/4750468/627193
        node.InnerHtml = Regex.Replace(node.InnerHtml,
            @"((http|ftp|https):\/\/[\w\-_]+(\.[\w\-_]+)+([\w\-\.,@?^=%&amp;:/~\+#]*[\w\-\@?^=%&amp;/~\+#])?)",
            "<a target='_blank' href='$1'>$1</a>");

    }

    for (int i = 0; i < node.ChildNodes.Count; i++) // Go for child nodes
    {
        node.ChildNodes[i] = Linkify(node.ChildNodes[i]);
    }
    return node;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Use html parser like [HtmlAgility Pack](https://html-agility-pack.net/). Select only text nodes and then search for links in them. That way you won't touch existing links. Depending on how precise you need to be you may use a regex.

For example

```
var doc = new HtmlDocument();
doc.LoadHtml(html);
Regex r = new Regex(@"(https?://[^\s]+)");
var textNodes = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//text()");

foreach (var textNode in textNodes) {
    var text = textNode.GetDirectInnerText();
    var withLinks = r.Replace(text, "<a href=\"$1\">$1</a>");
    textNode.InnerHtml = withLinks;
}
```

[Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/zo1eOV)

Regex to check correctly for links can get quite complicated. Check other answers here on SO.

Comment: Your example might generate an empty a tag before existing a tag.